# ASP.NET Core 6 ReactJS Web App on Linux has issues with IDX10634: Unable to create the SignatureProvider

Tags: linux, apache, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have deployed an ASP.NET 6 solution based on the ASP.NET 6 ReactJS template into a Linux CentOS/Apache hosting environment.

According to the error message provided below, It seems I need to alter the algorithm for the signature provider, yet I am at a loss of how exactly to do this.

```
System.NotSupportedException: IDX10634: Unable to create the SignatureProvider.
Algorithm: 'RS256', SecurityKey: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey, KeyId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', InternalId: 'xxxxxxx'.' is not supported. The list of supported algorithms is available here: https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/supported-algorithms
```

I have found several FAQs indicating to use ECDSA or similar instead, but no real examples of how exactly to implement this within my type of solution with examples of modifications in Program.cs or similar.

I would appreciate any tips of thoughts on this!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OpenSSL to create your own ECDSA key using:

```
#Create P256 ECDSA Private key
openssl genpkey -algorithm EC -pkeyopt ec_paramgen_curve:P-256 -aes256 -out p256-private.pem

# Optionally, if you want to extract the public key:
openssl ec -in p256-private.pem -pubout -out p256-public.pe

# Create certificat file
openssl req -new -x509 -key p256-private-key.pem -days 365 -subj "/CN=MyP256Cert" -out p256-cert.crt

# Crete the PFX file
openssl req -new -x509 -key p256-private-key.pem -days 365 -subj "/CN=MyP256Cert" -out p256-cert.crt
```

Then you can load it in C# using:

```
var ecdsaCert = new X509Certificate2("es256.pfx", "password");
SecurityKey ecdsaPrivateKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(ecdsaCert.GetECDsaPrivateKey());
```

You can add it to IdentityServer using something like this:

```
// Add ES256 (ECDSA using P-256 and SHA-256)
builder.AddSigningCredential(GetECDsaPrivateKey(p256Cert), IdentityServerConstants.ECDsaSigningAlgorithm.ES256);
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried with cert;

`string keyFile = "/home/somepath/cert.pfx";
    var ecdsaCert = new X509Certificate2(keyFile, "pass");
    SecurityKey ecdsaPrivateKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(ecdsaCert.GetECDsaPrivateKey());
    SigningCredentials s = new SigningCredentials(ecdsaPrivateKey, SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha384);    builder.Services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredential(s).AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
`
Yet I got the following error message: **Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"**

Comment: The key ID used to sign the key must also be found in the IDentityServer discovery JWKS endpoint, is it?

Comment: My JWKS endpoint is unfortunately broken, so I cannot verify this key ID. I get a nullrenferenceexception on it. 

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
object.GetType()
Duende.IdentityServer.ResponseHandling.DiscoveryResponseGenerator.CreateJwkDocumentAsync() in DiscoveryResponseGenerator.cs`

Comment: To addon to my comment above, locally the JWKS endpoint works @tore-nestenius

Comment: This is unfortunately still an issue for me... Error unprotecting key with kid xxxx, the key xxxx was not found in the ke ring and the jwt token has in invalid signature, so something is still way off with the signature I assume @tore-nestenius?

Comment: Do look inside the access token, the same kid should be found in the JWKS endpoint. Another thing is that the API that receives the token must have the same authority as the issuer of the token. Are they really the same? (Authority property inside the AddJwtBearer handler.

Comment: Hi again @tore-nestenius. I have verified that the issuer and authority for the token are 100% correxct. However, when it comes to the kid I am not able to verify as the JWKS endpoint is broken with a nullref-exception, as per abovementioned comment.

Comment: I would check the logs, as I think IdentitiServer would complain in the logs if the keys are not ok! Set the debug level to Debug in your IdentityServer instance.

Comment: I would also suggest to create a new IdentityServer setup and just focus on getting the keys right. Are you sure the keys you provide actually contains the private key?

Comment: They should contain the same key. I am using the ECDSA384 certificate installed on the linux server for the domain, and then I used it with AddSigningCredential(cert).